# Weird error preventing me from export after I move vertex/face/edge

Tags: add-on

I've been recently working on something that's called "Frankensteining"in JK3 game in Blender. I downloaded the plugin suite (for import/export models from the game) and I started the work.

However! Everytime I edit a mesh in any way (move vertex, edge, or face - moving the object itself is okay) and try to export it, this is the error I get: http://scr.hu/22as/t58y6

The model doesn't export itself. I mean, the issue is horribly annoying, I can't do anything because of that (since I can't modify any meshes) and I have no idea how to fix the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that your mesh is lacking UV coordinates. Unwrap your mesh (in edit mode, select all vertices `A` and unwrap `U` - `Unwrap`

Then try your export again.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. Here is the screenshot of another, similiar error that popped out: http://scr.hu/22as/vs6s4. And the mesh itself, I guess lost it's UV Mapping? And now doesn't look really well :/

Btw, I'm sorry for response, I'm still getting used to this site.